# Isotropy groups of elements in the same face of the fundamental weyl chamber are equal

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $T$ be a maximal torus of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{t}$.

We have the root decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}_ \mathbb{C}$ $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C}=\mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C} \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in R}\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ where $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha:\lbrace X \in \mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C},[H,X]=\alpha(H)X, H\in \mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C} \rbrace$.

Let $\mathfrak{t}^*_+: =\lbrace \lambda \in \mathfrak{t}^*_\mathbb{C}, B(\lambda, \alpha)\geq 0, \forall \alpha \in R\rbrace$ be the fundamental weyl chamber, where $B$ denotes the killing form.

Let $R_\sigma$ be  a subset of $R$. We define a the face $\sigma:= \lbrace \lambda \in \mathfrak{t}^*_\mathbb{C}, B(\lambda, \alpha) = 0, \alpha \in R_\sigma \rbrace$.

I'm trying to understand the proof which says that if $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \sigma$, then their isotropy groups by the coadjoint a action are equal, and the point that I didn't understand in this proof is the following: Let $\alpha$ be a root, then we have $B(\lambda_1, \alpha)=0 $ iff $B(\lambda_2, \alpha)=0 $?